# почему элементы массива не сравнивает?

Tags: c++

Вам дана матрица NxM с NxM числами внутри.
Ваша задача - найти строку, в которой общее количество положительных элементов больше.
Входные данные:
Первая строка содержит N и M (1<= N ,M <= 100).
Затем вводятся N строк, каждая из которых содержит ровно M чисел.

Выход:
Выходные данные должны содержать индекс строки, в которой общее количество положительных элементов больше.
Если в каждой строке одинаковое количество положительных элементов, выведите "Числа равны".
N.B. Гарантируется, что только в одном ряду сразу будет больше положительных элементов, чем в других.

Samples:
1:
Input:
2 3
1 -1 3
2 2 2

Output:
2

2:
Input:
3 4
1 1 -3 1
-4 2 2 1
1 -2 2 1

Output:
Numbers are equal

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    void comp (int n, int m) {
        int str, max = 0;
        int chek = 0;
        int *count = new int[n];
        count[n] = {0};
        int slau[n][m];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                cin >> slau[i][j];
                if (slau[i][j] > 0)
                    count[i]++;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
                if (count[i] != count[j]) {
                    chek = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        if (chek != 1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    if (count[i] > max) {
                        max = count[i];
                    str = i;
                    }
                }

            cout << str + 1 << endl;
        }
        else
            cout << "Numbers are equal";
    }

    int main(){
        int n, m;
        cin >> n >> m;
        comp (n, m);

        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Код у вас в принципе верный, но есть несколько ошибок.
В начале у вас выход за пределы массива. В создали массив из условно 5 элементов, а потом в шестой элемент записали ноль `count[5] = 0;`

```
int *count = new int[n];
count[n] = {0}; // это уже за пределами массива, т.к. индексы начинаются с 0
```

Вторая ошибка - созданный через `new[]` массив заполнен случайными числами. А далее в программе вы подсчитываете элементы через `count[i]++;`

```
if (slau[i][j] > 0)
   count[i]++;
```

Третья ошибка - вы долго (и не совсем правильно) искали признак равенства/неравенства положительных элементов в строках, а потом реагируете наоборот.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
       if (count[i] != count[j])
           chek = 1;

if (chek != 1) // максимум ищете если все строки равны, а должно быть наоборот!
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
       if (count[i] > max) 
       {
           max = count[i];
           str = i;
       }
```

Ну и дальше просто комментарии.
Почему вы по-разному создаете массивы? Вообще-то по стандарту правильно создавать динамический массив через `new`.

```
int *count = new int[n];  // здесь через new
int slau[n][m];           // здесь через объявление - почему?
```

По первой ошибке - видимо вы всё-таки хотели инициализировать массив нулями. Тогда надо было написать так:

```
int *count = new int[n]{0};  // создать массив и сразу инициализировать нулями
```

Проверку разного количества элементов в массиве `count[]` не нужно делать сравнивая каждый с каждым. Достаточно линейно 1 раз пройти по массиву сравнивая соседние элементы и если будет хоть одно отличие - установить флаг  `check`. А следующий цикл - поиск максимума, тоже делается за 1 проход! Так самое то - объединить их. Ну и по логике `check` должен быть логическим типом:

```
bool check = true;
max = count[0];
str = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
   if (i<n-1 and count[i] != count[i+1] )
       check = false;
   if (count[i] > max) 
   {
       max = count[i];
       str = i;
   }
}

if(check)
    cout << "Numbers are equal" << endl;
else
    cout << str + 1 << endl;
```

Ну и никогда не надо забывать освобождать ранее выделенную память.

```
delete[] count;
```